# How to upgrade the BIOS in a HP ProBook 6560b via the HP_TOOLS partition?

Tags: hp, bios

I recently discovered the there is a BIOS Update version F.28 available for my (work) notebook which is a HP ProBook 6560b booting with version F.20. I hope that this might fix the always-running fans in that machine.

The BIOS Update is available as a SoftPaq for download here:

- ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp59001-59500/sp59012.exe
- ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp59001-59500/sp59012.cva (text/ini file describing the contents)

According to the BIOS help I should find a BIN and a SIG file in there with the same name as the BIOS variant (which is `68SCE` according to dmidecode).  That one should be placed on the `HP_TOOLS` partition into the directory `/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/New` and it can be upgraded through the BIOS (if a `HpBiosUpdate.efi` module exists in `/Hewlett-Packard/BIOSUpdate`). It looks like everything is prepared properly:

```
# mount /dev/disk/by-label/HP_TOOLS /mnt/
# ls -lR /mnt/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS*
/mnt/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS:
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 21  2011 Current
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 21  2011 New
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 21  2011 Previous

/mnt/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/Current:
total 2564
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2621440 Dec 21  2011 68SCE.BIN
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     256 Dec 21  2011 68SCE.SIG

/mnt/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/New:
total 0

/mnt/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/Previous:
total 0

/mnt/Hewlett-Packard/BIOSUpdate:
total 2112
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 259072 Aug 31  2010 CryptRSA32.efi
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 443904 Aug 31  2010 CryptRSA.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 706528 Mar 28  2011 HpBiosUpdate32.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    256 Mar 28  2011 HpBiosUpdate32.s09
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    256 Mar 28  2011 HpBiosUpdate32.sig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 722848 Mar 28  2011 HpBiosUpdate.efi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     51 Dec 21 23:59 HpBiosUpdate.log
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    256 Mar 28  2011 HpBiosUpdate.s09
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    256 Mar 28  2011 HpBiosUpdate.sig
```

Unfortunately are there no BIN and SIG files in the SoftPaq, only a CAB file which contains files which might be the correct ones but are just named `Rom.*`.  There is also a `ROM.CAB` which contains some `Rom`-files as well:

```
# curl -O ftp://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp59001-59500/sp59012.exe
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 22.0M  100 22.0M    0     0   529k      0  0:00:42  0:00:42 --:--:--  355k
# 7za x -osp59012 sp59012.exe 

7-Zip (A) [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,4 CPUs)

Processing archive: sp59012.exe

Extracting  /68SCE.CAB
Extracting  /68SCF.CAB
Extracting  /hpqflash/hpqRun.exe
Extracting  /hpqflash/map.ini
Extracting  /hpqflash/SP59012_E.exe
Extracting  /hpqflash/SP59012_F.exe
Extracting  /HPQFlash.exe
Extracting  /hpqRun.exe
Extracting  /map.ini
Extracting  /ROM.CAB
Extracting  /WSSP59012.rtf

Everything is Ok

Files: 11
Size:       25651054
Compressed: 23089672
# find sp59012 -name '*.CAB' | xargs -I_ cabextract -d _.d _
Extracting cabinet: sp59012/ROM.CAB
  extracting sp59012/ROM.CAB.d/Rom.bin
  extracting sp59012/ROM.CAB.d/Rom.sig
  extracting sp59012/ROM.CAB.d/ver.txt
  extracting sp59012/ROM.CAB.d/ver.sig
  extracting sp59012/ROM.CAB.d/efibios.sig

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: sp59012/68SCF.CAB
  extracting sp59012/68SCF.CAB.d/Rom.bin
  extracting sp59012/68SCF.CAB.d/Rom.sig
  extracting sp59012/68SCF.CAB.d/ver.txt
  extracting sp59012/68SCF.CAB.d/ver.sig
  extracting sp59012/68SCF.CAB.d/efibios.sig

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: sp59012/68SCE.CAB
  extracting sp59012/68SCE.CAB.d/Rom.bin
  extracting sp59012/68SCE.CAB.d/Rom.sig
  extracting sp59012/68SCE.CAB.d/ver.txt
  extracting sp59012/68SCE.CAB.d/ver.sig
  extracting sp59012/68SCE.CAB.d/efibios.sig

All done, no errors.
# cat sp59012/map.ini 
[SYSTEM_ID]

1619=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCE.CAB -phpqssm.bin
1618=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCF.CAB -phpqssm.bin 
1621=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCE.CAB -phpqssm.bin
161C=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCF.CAB -phpqssm.bin
161D=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCE.CAB -phpqssm.bin
1620=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCF.CAB -phpqssm.bin
177C=hpqflash.exe -s -a -f68SCE.CAB -phpqssm.bin
```

The `map.ini` points to the `68SCE.CAB` (`1619` is the mainboard's Id according to dmidecode).  I could try the files from that file.  But I don't want to brick my notebook.  Has anybody done this before successfully?

Comment: I have similar issue, did you manage to overcome yours? http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-EliteBook/Probook-6560b-BIOS-issue-with-update-from-FLASH-drive/td-p/6190287#.UiOy2jaw18G

Comment: No, I didn't dare trying it yet.  If you try user128547's suggestion, please let us know if it worked.  I still think there should be a way using the `HP_TOOLS` partition.

Answer (score 2):

The following method works for me with an HP Probook 6460b. I've used Virtualbox (Windows XP guest) with a USB flash drive connected to perform the steps below.

1. Extract `SP60365_E.exe`.
2. I found two files `SP60365_E.exe` and `SP60365_F.exe` (depends of your
   system) in `C:\SWSetup\SP60365\hpqflash`.
3. Exactly these files create bootable flash drive.
4. I created boot flash drive from Virtualbox

You can see my post [in this thread on the HP Forums](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware-Upgrades-Replacements/BIOS-Upgrade-for-HP-probook-6460b-without-Windows/td-p/2372581/page/2).

Comment: Great to see it's possible. However, I don't quite understand the last two steps and I don't see these these steps explained in the link you've posted. Could you explain a bit more about the last two steps?

Comment: You mean you executed the extracted SP60365_x.exe in your Virtualboxed Windows and let it create a bootable USB stick which you used to flash the BIOS?

Comment: P.S.: I think your way of doing things should work (I will try) but I'm still interested in solution which uses the HP_TOOLS partition.

Answer (score 1):

To update BIOS on ProBook 11 G2

1. Get last BIOS from hp.com
2. Format usb drive using mkfs.fat
3. Create these directories in my usb:

   ```
   /EFI/HP/BIOS/New 
   /EFI/HP/BIOS/Previous 
   /EFI/HP/BIOSUpdate   
   /Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/New 
   /Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/Previous   
   /Hewlett-Packard/BIOSUpdate
   ```
4. Extract `spXXXX.exe` in `/EFI/HP/BIOS/New` and in `/Hewlett-Packard/BIOS/New`
5. Copy `/EFI/HP/BIOS/New/BIOSUpdate/*` in `/EFI/HP/BIOSUpdate` and in `/Hewlett-Packard/BIOSUpdate`
6. Activate bios option "boot from usb"
7. Using BIOS menu "Update BIOS from USB"